# asp.net json serializer: register converter

Tags: asp.net, json

I have some code like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new MyObjectModel() });
```

What does the RegisterConverters command do?

Thanks.

Comment: @JakubKonecki Please don't post LMGTFY links. They are useless noise and they help no one. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64453/shall-we-spam-flag-lmgtfy-links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it registers custom JS converter implementation.
check example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx

Comment: What does it mean to register a converter?

Comment: means - when JavaScriptSerializer finds a property (item) of type specified in your converter SupportedTypes property, it will call your overrides of Serialize/Deserialize instead of base implementation.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that makes it clearer now; one-liner explanations work well!

Answer (score 0):

Select `RegisterConverters` method in Visual Studio and press F1.